# Do the new Canadian hotel quarantine requirements apply to non-residents?

Tags: canada, covid-19

Canada has introduced new quarantine requirements, starting February 22nd, requiring that some travelers entering the country stay at specific quarantine hotels until their molecular COVID test result is available (expected to take up to three days).

What I haven't been able to determine is if this applies only to Canadian residents returning from travel (many sources have positioned it this way), or also to non-residents entering under e.g., the family member or compassionate exemptions?

Comment: Why wouldn't they? What kind of sensible quarantine procedure excludes people based on nationality?

Comment: are you interested in both air travel and arrival at land borders?  The rules you're describing apply to air travel (as @DJClayworth's answer says). For land borders, the new rules going into effect soon are that (1) all entering travelers will need proof of a negative COVID test from the preceding 72 hours, (2) 14-day quarantine after arrival. No hotels etc.

Comment: @user253751 Assuming government regulations are sensible might not be a good starting place.

Comment: I would expect possibly even harsher requirements for non-residents than for residents, certainly not softer ones.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- You can't assume *old* government regulations are *still* sensible, but they rarely put regulations in place without a reason.

Answer (score 16):

The [announcements of these regulations](https://www.canada.ca/en/transport-canada/news/2021/01/government-of-canada-introduces-further-restrictions-on-international-travel.html) state they apply to

> all air travellers arriving in Canada, with very limited exceptions

I would assume you have to comply with these regulations unless you have specifically been told you do not.

Comment: They also don’t apply at land borders although you’d still have to do a 14 day quarantine, even if you’re already vaccinated.

Comment: But if you are arriving at a land border, maybe there would be more exceptions?  At least that’s what I’m wondering.